# Comparing Datetime in Django

Tags: python, django

I am working with Django. My database has a `Schedule` table with the following fields:

- `startingTime` content `DateTimeField`
- `durationInMinits` content `IntegerField`

It means that any work starts at `startingTime` and lasts for `durationInMinits` (numeric value, in **minute** unit).

If a work is started at `April 22, 2021, 6 p.m.` and it's `durationInMinits` is `30` minutes, then it will running till `April 22, 2021, 6:30 p.m`.

I need to determine, does the work running time belong to the `current time`?

Here I will determine `current time` by using `timezone.now()` function. kindly provide any suggestion to determine it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will send that your current time belongs to your defined range

```
startingTime <= timezone.now() < startingTime + timezone.timedelta(minutes=durationInMinits)
```